# how to replace logo's(images) based on the background theme

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two different images(logo), one for dark theme(it has light colored logo) and one for light theme(it has dark colored logo).

User has freedom to choose either dark theme or light theme.
But i am facing difficulty while replacing logo's. Can anybody please help me out with this?

My two .png images are named as lightlogo.png and darklogo.png. When the page loads user gets to see dark themed UI.

Here is my code to display logo

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
    <image  src="../images/lightlogo.png" alt="image" id="imag"   class="hidden-xs " />
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is my code for theming

```
<div id="icon-div">
  <p>
    <i class="material-icons dp48">loop</i>
  </p>
  <div id="icon-element">
    <input type="button" id="light" value="light-theme"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my js where user can change the theme and i am trying to add image for light background(light theme)

```
$('#light').click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "light-theme") {
    $(this).val("dark-theme");
    changeCSS("styleLight.css", 0)
  }
  else {
    $(this).val("light-theme");
    changeCSS("styleDark.css", 0).attr("src" , "../images/darklogo.png");
  }
});

function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {

  var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

  var newlink = document.createElement("link");
  newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
  newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  newlink.setAttribute("href", "/stylesheets/"+cssFile);

  document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
}
```

Comment: How about putting the graphic in the css as a background-image?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, I have removed changing image src inside javascript function.

```
$('#light').click(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == "light-theme") {
    $(this).val("dark-theme");
    changeCSS("styleLight.css", 0)
    $('#imag').attr('src', "../images/darklogo.png");
  } else {
    $(this).val("light-theme");
    changeCSS("styleDark.css", 0)
    //.attr("src" , "../images/darklogo.png");
    $('#imag').attr('src', "../images/lightlogo.png");
  }
});

function changeCSS(cssFile, cssLinkIndex) {

   var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(cssLinkIndex);

   var newlink = document.createElement("link");
   newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
   newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
   newlink.setAttribute("href", "/stylesheets/"+cssFile);

}
```

Problem is you cannot use `attr()` for javascript function.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this, just have a wrapper class for the theme and then change the logo src attribute when changing theme.

```js
$('#changeTheme').click(function() {
 var themeWrapper = $('#themeWrapper');
  var themeLogo = $('#themeLogo');
  
  if (themeWrapper.attr('class') === 'light-theme') {
    themeWrapper.attr('class', 'dark-theme');
    themeLogo.attr('src', '../images/darklogo.png');
  }
  else {
    themeWrapper.attr('class', 'light-theme');
    themeLogo.attr('src', '../images/lightlogo.png');
  }
});
```

```css
#themeWrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
.light-theme {
  background-color: #999;
  color: black;
}
.dark-theme {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="themeWrapper" class="light-theme">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
      <image  src="../images/lightlogo.png" alt="Theme logo" id="themeLogo" class="hidden-xs" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>Random text...</div>
  <button type="button" id="changeTheme">Change theme</button>
</div>
```

Note: The logo has no working src in this example, but the src attribute changes.

Answer (score 1):

Make a simple function that just changes the src of the icon, and that's it.
And call it from the same button that changes the theme.

```js
function change(){
    if($("#imag").attr('src') != "http://www.thetechnologygeeks.com/images/icons/icon_mad.png"){
      $("#imag").attr("src","http://www.thetechnologygeeks.com/images/icons/icon_mad.png");
    } else {
      $("#imag").attr("src","https://filmscoremonthly.com/board/pics/icon6.gif");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<a href="#!" class="brand-logo">
<image  src="https://filmscoremonthly.com/board/pics/icon6.gif" alt="image" id="imag"   class="hidden-xs " />
</a>
</div>


<button type="button" onclick="change()">Click Me!</button>
```